# Why does resizing in graphicsmagick yield larger file size

Tags: image-processing, image-resizing, graphicsmagick

**Preamble:** I have a list of several thousand jp2 images that I need to quickly check for content. (I have more computer processing time than physical time.) There are several conversion steps that I am planning to take to reduce the file size from 200+k to less than 50k. One of these steps was to resize the image. The original images are all 4k+x2k+ in size. However, when I used graphicmagick's convert command the file size doubled although the new file has smaller dimensions. *Less is more!* The command I used was `convert -resize 1000x1000 myOldFile.jp2 myNewFile.jp2`

**My question:** *Why did the file size double and what can I do to decrease the image dimensions while at the same time reducing the file size?*

**Results:**
The result of `identify -verbose` for both files is as follows.

*Old File*

```
Image: myOldFile.jp2
  Format: JP2 (JPEG-2000 File Format Syntax)
  Mime type: image/jp2
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 4368x2912+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: TrueColor
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianess: Undefined
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 12719616
    Red:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 242 (0.94902)
      mean: 161.286 (0.632496)
      standard deviation: 83.2707 (0.326552)
      kurtosis: -0.933893
      skewness: -0.997317
      entropy: 0.706322
    Green:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 232 (0.909804)
      mean: 151.98 (0.596001)
      standard deviation: 76.5239 (0.300094)
      kurtosis: -0.952932
      skewness: -0.979073
      entropy: 0.729028
    Blue:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 207 (0.811765)
      mean: 122.977 (0.482262)
      standard deviation: 63.5478 (0.249207)
      kurtosis: -0.9993
      skewness: -0.936829
      entropy: 0.775844
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 242 (0.94902)
      mean: 145.414 (0.570253)
      standard deviation: 74.4475 (0.291951)
      kurtosis: -1.06722
      skewness: -0.805503
      entropy: 0.737065
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 4368x2912+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: JPEG2000
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2019-08-01T15:14:22-07:00
    date:modify: 2009-06-03T13:13:55-07:00
    signature: ffd44383040859b7138d337c52e2545e2b49601f949a2bbbdfc7b8592d60360b
  Artifacts:
    filename: myOldFile.jp2
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 268346B
  Number pixels: 12.7196M
  Pixels per second: 7.43837MB
  User time: 1.550u
  Elapsed time: 0:02.710
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.9-40 Q16 x86_64 2019-05-16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

*New File*

```
Image: myNewFile.jp2
  Format: JP2 (JPEG-2000 File Format Syntax)
  Mime type: image/jp2
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1000x667+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: TrueColor
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianess: Undefined
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 667000
    Red:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 254 (0.996078)
      mean: 160.789 (0.630545)
      standard deviation: 83.1402 (0.32604)
      kurtosis: -0.923213
      skewness: -1.00025
      entropy: 0.710373
    Green:
      min: 2  (0.00784314)
      max: 245 (0.960784)
      mean: 151.482 (0.594048)
      standard deviation: 76.3802 (0.29953)
      kurtosis: -0.941261
      skewness: -0.981966
      entropy: 0.732809
    Blue:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 221 (0.866667)
      mean: 122.48 (0.480313)
      standard deviation: 63.3749 (0.248529)
      kurtosis: -0.985942
      skewness: -0.939624
      entropy: 0.777783
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 254 (0.996078)
      mean: 144.917 (0.568302)
      standard deviation: 74.2984 (0.291366)
      kurtosis: -1.05759
      skewness: -0.80746
      entropy: 0.740322
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 1000x667+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: JPEG2000
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2019-08-01T15:40:21-07:00
    date:modify: 2019-08-01T15:40:21-07:00
    signature: 061752e248846335b5f064c85e83ff71542f7ddd55f5327cf146b8aacd685285
  Artifacts:
    filename: myNewFile.jp2
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 511396B
  Number pixels: 667000
  Pixels per second: 4.16875MB
  User time: 0.160u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.160
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.9-40 Q16 x86_64 2019-05-16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Comment: `convert -monochrome myOldFile.jp2 mono.jp2` causes the new file to grow 10 times from 268KB to 2.7 MB. Ugh!

Comment: Likely the default compression quality setting is different from the one used to write the original images.

Comment: You are not using GraphicsMagick. The last line of your listing says `Version: ImageMagick 6.9.9-40 Q16`. So actually Imagemagick and at that an old version. Perhaps you should try to upgrade to a current version. Also check your version of openjpeg and make sure it is current. Then also see the Imagemagick defines that you can use to control the JP2 output image at https://imagemagick.org/script/jp2.php.